# Firebase query of sorted data within Google Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

how does one query sorted data from firebase inside firebase functions? For example:

```
exports.readStore = functions.database.ref('/categories/{userId}')
    .onWrite(event => { 
      admin.database().ref(`categories/${event.params.userId}`).orderByChild('name').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        console.log('snapshot', snapshot.val());
      });
      return admin.database().ref(`read/${event.params.userId}`).child('sortOrder').set({1: 2});
    });
```

Is this a valid syntax given that the promise from the query will/might not be resolved before the function returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick in Cloud Functions is to use `once('value'`, which gives you all matching nodes at once.

```
exports.readStore = functions.database.ref('/categories/{userId}')
.onWrite(event => { 
  let query = admin.database().ref(`categories/${event.params.userId}`).orderByChild('name');
  return query.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      console.log('child', child.val());
    });
    // TODO: use the result determined above
    return admin.database().ref(`read/${event.params.userId}`).child('sortOrder').set({1: 2});
  });
});
```

Use `snapshot.forEach()` to ensure you loop over the child nodes in the order that you requested them.

I'm not fully sure what you're trying to do in the `set()`, so you'll need to adapt to your needs.